# Protobuf-net deserialization exception Number overflow

Tags: protobuf-net

I am getting exception while deserialising protobuf data in dot net. I am getting Number Overflow exception. Is there any way i can get which field is giving the error as the Proto Structure is pretty large.

Logs are like this

```
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : Proto DEserialize exception : System.OverflowException: Number overflow.
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.TryReadUInt32VariantWithoutMoving (bool,uint&) <0x00328>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadUInt32Variant (bool) <0x0002f>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadInt32 () <0x00057>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at (wrapper dynamic-method) King.Data.GetUserdataInfoStruct.proto_2 (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <0x006c3>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.Serializers.CompiledSerializer.ProtoBuf.Serializers.IProtoSerializer.Read (object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <0x00037>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.Deserialize (int,object,ProtoBuf.ProtoReader) <0x00113>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore (ProtoBuf.ProtoReader,System.Type,object,bool) <0x0006b>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream,object,System.Type,ProtoBuf.SerializationContext) <0x000a7>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream,object,System.Type) <0x0003b>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<King.Data.GetUserdataInfoStruct> (System.IO.Stream) <0x00043>
09-12 12:55:50.318  9188  9507 E Unity   : at King.Proto.KingProtBufSerialize
```

Comment: How large is "pretty large" in this context? Vexingly, we do track the offset internally (although not the active field/tree), but this isn't exposed by `OverflowException`. Also: what lib version is this?

Comment: pretty large means the structure has 20 fields with few fields are again proto struct.Even With a structure of 10 fields how i know that issue is coming in this field.